# Accessing rapidjson::Document array by index

Tags: c++, arrays, cocos2d-x, rapidjson

I have this code:

```
Document dataDoc;
dataDoc.SetArray();
Document::AllocatorType &allocator = dataDoc.GetAllocator();

for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << "set_" << i + 1 << "_data";

    Document doc;
    doc.Parse<0>(UserDefault::getInstance()->getStringForKey(ss.str().c_str()).c_str());
    dataDoc.PushBack(doc, allocator);
}
```

There's a `rapidjson::Document` "dataDoc" and I convert it to an array. Then I fill the array with `Document` objects that contain JSON objects that are fetched from `cocos2d::UserDefault` and parsed appropriately.

This is the JSON object that is added to the dataDoc:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "phone": "123",
      "address": "Address 456"
    },
    {
      "name": "Helen",
      "phone": "123",
      "address": "Address 456"
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "phone": "123",
      "address": "Address 456"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the dataDoc array contains 10 of these objects.

I know that I can handle one object like this:

```
Document doc;
rapidjson::Value &people = doc["people"];
string name = people[0]["name"].GetString();
```

But how can I access, for example, the first object in the dataDoc array by index and get the name value as above?

**Edit**

Tried also with this code:

```
vector<string> jsons;
jsons.push_back("{\"people\":[{\"name\":\"Peter\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"address\":\"Address 456\"},{\"name\":\"Helen\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"address\":\"Address 456\"},{\"name\":\"John\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"address\":\"Address 456\"}]}");
jsons.push_back("{\"people\":[{\"name\":\"Peter\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"address\":\"Address 456\"},{\"name\":\"Helen\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"address\":\"Address 456\"},{\"name\":\"John\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"address\":\"Address 456\"}]}");
jsons.push_back("{\"people\":[{\"name\":\"Peter\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"address\":\"Address 456\"},{\"name\":\"Helen\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"address\":\"Address 456\"},{\"name\":\"John\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"address\":\"Address 456\"}]}");

Document dataDoc;
dataDoc.SetArray();
Document::AllocatorType &allocator = dataDoc.GetAllocator();

for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    Document doc;
    doc.Parse<0>(jsons.at(i).c_str());
    dataDoc.PushBack(doc, allocator);
}

auto &people = dataDoc[0]["people"];
```

But it gave me the same error. It points to line 1688 in "document.h" located at `...\cocos2d\external\json\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there seems to be an issue in your code the way you create `doc` - You need to provide the allocator of `dataDoc`:

```
Document doc(&allocator);
```

---

Then, `rapidjson::Document` inherits from `rapidjson::Value`, so you can simply treat it as a value and use the `[]` operator:

```
auto &people = dataDoc[0]["people"];
```

You can also iterate through the whole document:

```
for (auto &doc: dataDoc.getArray()) {
    auto &people = doc["people"];
}
```

Prior to C++11:

```
for (Value::ConstValueIterator itr = dataDoc.Begin(); 
     itr != dataDoc.End(); ++itr) {
    auto &people = (*itr)["people"];
}
```

Comment: For some reason this gives me an "Assertion failed!" error: "Expression: rhs.IsString()".

Comment: @Deeds Which one?

Comment: @Deeds I wrote `doc` instead of `dataDoc` in the first snippet, maybe it was the problem... Answer edited.

Comment: Yes, I tried `auto &people = dataDoc[0]["people"];`, but it gives that error.

Comment: @Deeds I have tested by recreating the object you showed and it works, so there is something that is not consistent in your question. Could you post a code that does not rely on an external source for the creation of the object so that I can test it?

Comment: @Deeds I am not sure the issue is what the `auto &people = ...` line. I tried your code with a simple output to `std::cout` using a `Writer<OStreamWrapper>`, and I get the same error, so the issue is probably with the creation of `dataDoc`.

Comment: @Deeds Everything is fixed if you provide `&allocator` to `doc` (see updated answer).